# Renamed columns, rspec seems to be seeing old columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using rspec and factory_girl.

i renamed columns in the db, yet my factories are returning the old columns.

How can I reset this cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't run `rake db:test:prepare` to copy over the schema into your test database.